# Mojave Terminal not starting nodes from runnodes (Corda deployNodes)

Tags: corda

When starting `./build/nodes/deployNodes` in macOS Mojave 10.14.1, the terminal opens but does not start up the tabs corresponding to each node defined in the `deployNodes` task in Gradle.

Specifically looking at the tutorial section [here](https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-running.html#running-the-nodes).

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 5):

To fix this, go to System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Privacy -> Accessibility and make sure that Terminal is in the list and checked (enabled).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are running nodes from IntelliJ terminal you have to add it and Terminal to Accessibility and Automation sections.

Accessibility:
[image: Accessibility]
Automation:
[image: Automation]

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue (on Mojave) even after adding Intellij and terminal to accessibility and automation.

The work around is to manually start the nodes via; `java -jar corda.jar` in each nodes directory.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by resetting security permissions on OSX. I could not work out how to add Java into the Accessability group.

Conditions apply in this paragraph! If you type 'tccutil reset AppleEvents' in a Terminal then this will clear *all* the security associations. Then when you run applications again you'll get prompted to allow or block. So if you do this, then try ./runnodes again you should see a bunch of dialogs which you can click yes to. The nodes should now start ok.

Also, in your security settings you should see 'Java' appear in the Accessibility group.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessibility and automation, to make this work on Catalina 10.15.7 I had to add terminal to the *Developer Tools* section instead of accessibility and automation:

[image]